# ".objc_class_name_ABPersonViewController", referenced from:

Tags: objective-c, iphone

whenever i add  this line of code
ABPersonViewController *personController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];

im getting this error message 
".objc_class_name_ABPersonViewController", referenced from:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error generated by the linker when it can't find a definition for the symbol `.objc_class_name_ABPersonViewController`. This symbol is for the `ABPersonViewController` defined in AdressBook.framework. So, you need to link your application with AddressBook.framework. To do so, select the application target in the Targets group of the Groups & Files pane in Xcode. Select Get Info from the target's context menu. In the "General" tab of the info panel, add AddressBook.framework to the "Linked Libraries" list.

Comment: Can u let me know how to use ABPesronViewController to display a contact from address book

Comment: @Pinky I think that's best put into a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link your app to AddressBook framework.

Comment: Hey Thanx,,i have include AddressBook framework in my project also included the header file

Comment: You need not only include it in your header file, but link it to your project at compile time.